# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.Answers.get()Lorg/mockito/stubbing/Answer;

Tags: spring-boot, maven, mockito, powermock, vaadin8

I am trying to upgrade the spring boot version from 2.2.4 to 2.6.6. I'm able to compile the application successfully and I'm able to start the application. But when i'm trying to run the tests, all the tests are failing with one error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.Answers.get()Lorg/mockito/stubbing/Answer;

I'm getting same error for all the tests.

Here is my main pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
    <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>imc-core</module>
        <module>imc-restapi</module>
        <module>imc-ui</module>
    </modules>

    <name>imc-parent</name>
    <description>IMC</description>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>build.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.8</version>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>groovy-vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-vaadin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suppressionFile>owasp-false-positives.xml</suppressionFile>
                        <failBuildOnCVSS>8</failBuildOnCVSS>
                        <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Here is my ui pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
        <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>imc-ui</artifactId>
    <name>imc-ui</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.14.2</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.14.2</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <vaadin4spring.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</vaadin4spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>imc-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.25</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.58</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-archaius -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-archaius</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-consul -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-function-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-function-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-jmx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-sass-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.haijian</groupId>
            <artifactId>exporter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>VAADIN</directory>
                <targetPath>VAADIN</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>retrospect</directory>
                <targetPath>retrospect</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1G</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>false</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your `Powermock` library conflicts with `Mockito`.

You can try the following dependency version and order in your pom.xml. Note that the main idea is to give priority to `Mockito` than `Powermock`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```